# android wifi range change

Tags: android, range, wifi

I have developed an application in android to check the WiFi connectivity. I wanted to know whether my device is in the range of a particular wifi hotspot. I can use the following code to get the list of wifi hotspots available.

```
List<android.net.wifi.ScanResult> mScanResults = myWifiManager.getScanResults();
```

But in my case we have a very big office with lots of wifi hotspots. So I am connected to wifi_hp_1 and moving, then when I reach wifi_hp_2, the scanning is not happening. I have registered a broadcast receiver for

```
ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
```

But the scanning is not happening, if I am in the range of hotspot1 and reached in the range of hotspot2, but still the signals of hotspot1 is available.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we handle it in our app:

```
private WifiManager wifi;

private BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
            ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo info = mgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (info == null) {
                scanForWiFiNetworks();
                setScanningEnabled(true);

            } else if (!info.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
                setScanningEnabled(false);

                scanForWiFiNetworks();

            } else {
                scanForWiFiNetworks();
                setScanningEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver wifiStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
            setScanningEnabled(false);

            scan.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2500);
        }
    }
};

private Handler scan = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        setScanningEnabled(false);
        scanForWiFiNetworks();
    }
};

private Handler reenableScanning = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        reenableScanning.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        setScanningEnabled(true);
    };
};

private void scanForWiFiNetworks() {
    setScanningEnabled(false);

    mapConnections = new HashMap<String, String>();

    btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
    btnForget.setEnabled(false);
    btnUpdate.setEnabled(false);

    checkWiFiState();

    List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
    WifiInfo connectedWiFi = wifi.getConnectionInfo();

    String connected = "";

    ArrayList<String> listDupeCheck = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] listResults = new String[0];
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        if (!listDupeCheck.contains(results.get(i).SSID)) {
            if (connectedWiFi.getSSID() != null) {
                if ((connectedWiFi.getSSID().equalsIgnoreCase(results.get(i).SSID) || connectedWiFi.getSSID().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        "\"" + results.get(i).SSID + "\""))
                        && connectedWiFi.getSupplicantState().equals(SupplicantState.COMPLETED)) {
                    connected = "; " + GlobalVars.getMessageText(1159);// Connected

                } else {
                    connected = "";
                }

            } else {
                connected = "";
            }

            String connectionInfo = getMessageText(171) + ": " + results.get(i).SSID + ", " + getMessageText(1160) + ": "
                    + results.get(i).capabilities + connected;

            list.add(connectionInfo);

            mapConnections.put(connectionInfo, results.get(i).SSID);

            listDupeCheck.add(results.get(i).SSID);
        }
    }

    listResults = list.toArray(listResults);

    scan.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    setScanningEnabled(true);
}
```

Then in onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    IntentFilter wifiState = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    this.registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, filter);
    this.registerReceiver(wifiStateReceiver, wifiState);
    wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me what value you gave for filter and wifiState in you onCreate function? for registering the broadcast receiver.

Comment: Thank you very much. My requirement was, I have connected to Hotspot_1 and I reached Hotspot_2. But still my connection to Hotspot_1 is active. Still this work? Sorry for asking many questions.

Comment: With this code, you would have to, through user interaction, try to connect to Hotspot 2.  You want to automatically connect?

Comment: I don't want to connect automatically. But I want to know when Hotspot 2 is coming into the range without any user interaction.

Comment: Do you want just a toast - how do you want to notify the user?

Comment: The Hotspot2 is came into the range (when Hotspot1 is already connected), I just wan to show a toast. Or at that time I will invoking some webservices.